# Create Esri token authentication in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I want to create a Esri token-based authentication in PyQGIS using the generated token. I am using below code to achieve it. But while running the code I am only able to get the basic authentication rather than Esri token based authentication.

How can I get Esri token based authentication?

i am referring below link.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/authentication.html#term-Authentication-Method

````
authMgr = QgsApplication.authManager()
if authMgr.authenticationDatabasePath():
   # already initialized => we are inside a QGIS app.
   if authMgr.masterPasswordIsSet():
      msg = 'Authentication master password not recognized'
      assert authMgr.masterPasswordSame(password), msg
   else:
      msg = 'Master password could not be set'
      # The verify parameter checks if the hash of the password was
      # already saved in the authentication db
      assert authMgr.setMasterPassword(password,verify=True), msg
else:
    print("else auth db set")
    # outside qgis, e.g. in a testing environment => setup env var before
    # db init
    os.environ['QGIS_AUTH_DB_DIR_PATH'] = "/d/test/qgis-auth.db"
    msg = 'Master password could not be set'
    assert authMgr.setMasterPassword(password, True), msg
 
authMgr.init("//qgis-auth.db")

###### Get AuthID ######
namesAU_config_key = [name for name in authMgr.availableAuthMethodConfigs().keys()]
print(namesAU_config_key)

if len(namesAU_config_key) == 0:
   config = QgsAuthMethodConfig()
   config.setName('testing')
   config.setMethod('Esri-Token')
   config.setConfig('Token', self.token)
   assert config.isValid()
   authMgr.storeAuthenticationConfig(config)
   newAuthCfgId = config.id()
   assert newAuthCfgId```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3UzE.png
````

Comment: config.setConfig('token', self.token) should not be with capital "T"

Answer (score 2):

the config method used here is wrong

> `config.setMethod('Esri-Token')`

it should be

```
config.setMethod('EsriToken')
```

(without hyphen).

Then the Esri Token based authentication can work.